# How to correctly print values from clGetDeviceInfo

Tags: c, opencl

I am trying to print out the type of local memory:

```
cl_int err;
cl_device_local_mem_type type;
err = clGetDeviceInfo(
deviceId,
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE,
sizeof(cl_device_local_mem_type),
&type,
0 );

printf ("Memory type is %s=". type);
```

This is not working. Also if I use &type, even then it is working.

Do I need to do some type casting ?  Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Hope your post has the typo error `'.'` vs. `','` and not your code in `printf ("Memory type is %s=". type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cl_device_local_mem_type` type is just an unsigned integer, so you should be printing it with `%u`, not `%s`.

```
cl_int err;
cl_device_local_mem_type type;
err = clGetDeviceInfo(
deviceId,
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE,
sizeof(cl_device_local_mem_type),
&type,
0 );

printf ("Memory type is %u=", type);
```

You'll get either `1` or `2` back, which you can check in the `cl.h` header:

```
#define CL_LOCAL                                    0x1
#define CL_GLOBAL                                   0x2
```

Comment: So it is returning an int i.e 1, what do we conclude from this? does that mean that the local memory mapped to global ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer with what those values mean. You can check them in `cl.h`.